# Making a class to keep track of related strings

Tags: c#, string, class, list, dictionary

It is kind of funny, With the follwing class I know how my output should like but I could not figure it out how to hold the data for it.

Please see the code below:

```
    public class QuickFailureReportText
{
    public string[] device { get; set; }
    public string[] group { get; set; }
    public string[] pin { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        TextWriter tw;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        tw = new StringWriter(sb);

        tw.WriteLine("Quick Failure Report");

        foreach (string dev in device)
        {
            tw.WriteLine("Failures in " + dev);

            foreach (string grp in group)
            {
               tw.Write("Group " + grp + " : ");

                foreach(string p in pin)
                {
                    tw.Write(p + ", ");
                }
                tw.WriteLine(); //new line
            }
            tw.WriteLine(); //new line
        }

        return tw.ToString();
    }
}
```

So what I want to do, is I want be able to somohe relate the three different string "device, group, pin" somhow that a PIN belongs to a GROUP and a GROUP belongs to a DEVICE. how that can be possible?

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

---

**UPDATE**
Ok, I have a XML file that I can read data from it with no problem. the xml file looks like something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<DEVICES> 

  <device> 
    <name>device 1</name> 
    <groups> 
      <group>
      <group_name>group 1</group_name> 
      <pins> 
        <pin result="fail">A1</pin> 
        <pin result="pass">A2</pin> 
      </pins>
      </group>
      <group> 
      <group_name>group 2</group_name> 
      <pins> 
        <pin result="fail">B1</pin> 
        <pin result="pass">B2</pin> 
      </pins>
      </group>       
    </groups> 
  </device> 

</DEVICES>
```

So I want to gather the data from this XML(which may have a lot of devices) and using the class I wrote above, filter the failed pins.

Comment: No, it's not clear enough. Describe the data structure more clearly.

Comment: @David I have updated the question with more info. I am not sure if it is clear now or not. let me know again!

Comment: Little question, aren't tags <group_name> and <pins> nested in some <group> tag?

Comment: @Lucasus oh yeah...sorry I failed at showing an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written some code you can use to read required information from xml file, store in devices variable

```
public class Device
{
    public string Name;
    public Dictionary<string, Group> Groups = new Dictionary<string, Group>();
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Pins = new List<string>();
}

public class QuickFailureReportText
{
    public Dictionary<string, Device> devices = new Dictionary<string, Device>();

    public void AddLog(string deviceName, string groupName, string pin)
    {
        if (!devices.ContainsKey(deviceName))
            devices.Add(deviceName, new Device() 
                 { Name = deviceName, Groups = new Dictionary<string, Group>() });

        if (!devices[deviceName].Groups.ContainsKey(groupName))
            devices[deviceName].Groups.Add(groupName, new Group() 
                 { Name = groupName, Pins = new List<string>() });

        devices[deviceName].Groups[groupName].Pins.Add(pin);
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        TextWriter tw;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        tw = new StringWriter(sb);
        tw.WriteLine("Quick Failure Report");

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"devices.xml");
        foreach (XElement device in xDoc.XPathSelectElements("DEVICES/device"))
        {
            foreach (XElement group in device.XPathSelectElements("groups/group"))
            {
                foreach (XElement pin in group.XPathSelectElements("pins/pin"))
                {
                    if (pin.Attribute("result").Value == "fail")
                    {
                        AddLog(device.XPathSelectElement("name").Value,
                        group.XPathSelectElement("group_name").Value, pin.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var device in devices.Values)
        {
            tw.WriteLine("Failures in " + device.Name);

            foreach (var grp in device.Groups.Values)
            {
                tw.Write("Group " + grp.Name + " : ");

                foreach (string p in grp.Pins)
                {
                    tw.Write(p + ", ");
                }
                tw.WriteLine(); //new line
            }
            tw.WriteLine(); //new line
        }


        return tw.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = new QuickFailureReportText().ToString();
    }
}
```

Below is value of 's' string for your example file:

```
Quick Failure Report
Failures in device 1
Group group 1 : A1, 
Group group 2 : B1,
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
public class Device
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Pin> Pins = new List<Pin>();
}

public class Pin
{
    public string Name;
    public string Result;
}
```

Comment: so how I can maintain a relationship between these three class, while I may have more than one device?

Answer (score 1):

I would implement an object data model, using three classes:

`DEVICE` HAS `GROUP`

`GROUP` HAS `PIN`

---

**UPDATE**

Class 1:  `DEVICE`, with member field `list_of_groups` (you can use a different name)

Class 2:  `GROUP`, with member field `list_of_pins`

Class 3:  `PIN`, with member field `result` (boolean)

Comment: Can you please show a quick implemention example of this way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if you change the xml in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<DEVICES> 

  <device> 
    <name>device 1</name> 
    <groups> 
      <group>
      <group_name>group 1</group_name> 
      <pins> 
        <pin result="fail">A1</pin> 
        <pin result="pass">A2</pin> 
      </pins>
      </group>
      <group> 
      <group_name>group 2</group_name> 
      <pins> 
        <pin result="fail">B1</pin> 
        <pin result="pass">B2</pin> 
      </pins>
      </group>       
    </groups> 
  </device> 

</DEVICES>
```

So you can define the object `Device` tha contains a List of `Group` that contains a list of object `Pin`.